# Shiro authentication for ldap with zeppelin

Tags: authentication, ldap, shiro, apache-zeppelin

What should be the properties of ldap realm for shiro authentication to ldap group in company for zeppelin? I tried setting up some of the properties but it didn't work.

- `ldapRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm`
- `ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = uid={0},ou=Groups,o=company.com`
- `ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://ldap.company.com:389`
- `ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = simple`

Answer (score 1):

You should configure the property **ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment[ldap.searchBase]**, whose value is the same as **ldapRealm.userDnTemplate**, except **uid={0}**, for example:

```
ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment[ldap.searchBase]=ou=Groups,o=company.com
```